# How do I loop over 3 setInterval functions but chain them as promises so the resolve and move on?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, google-chrome-devtools

Assuming the `first()`, `second()`, and `third()` functions work, how do I chain them together asynchronously in a loop so that the first resolves, then the second has access to the DOM after first resolves, etc.

So I can click through similar DOM items and take 3 actions over and over?

```
// first() pops up a list of buttons I can click
var first = setInterval(function() {
  var expand = document.querySelector('a');
  expand.click();
}, 1000);

// second() chooses an item and clicks it
var second = setInterval(function() {
  var something = document.querySelector('a');
  something.click();
}, 1000);

// third then chooses the confirm button
var third = setInterval(function() {
  var area = document.querySelector('.class');
  var confirm = document.querySelector('.confirm');
  confirm.click();
}, 1000);


var times = 100;
var ran = 0;

while (ran < times) {
  return new Promise(function(res, rej) {
    first()
  }).then(function() {
    second()
  }).then(function() {
    third();
  }).then(function() {
    fourth();
  });

  ran++;
  console.log(ran);
}
```

Comment: If you want to go the Promise way then first I would suggest you to use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval` since you will be repeadetly promisifying them as promises resolve only once.

Comment: Why are these in a `setInterval()` at all?  `setInterval()` runs over and over and over until you clear the interval.

Answer (score 2):

**I think the simplest way to solve your problem is to wrap `setTimeout` in a `Promise` and then use `async`/`await`.** That way you can use the same control flow you already have set in place.

**You should use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`.** `setInterval` runs periodically at set intervals of time but your `while` loop already runs your code multiple times so you should use `setTimeout` instead which only runs the callback once.

To make things simpler, **I would wrap `setTimeout` in a `Promise`** so you can use `async` and `await`.

`async` is a modifier you place on functions that allows you to use the key word `await`. **What `await` does is it unwraps promises and waits for them to resolve** before running the next bit of code. It allows you to use simple synchronous control flow even if the code is actually asynchronous.

What I did is create an `async` function `main` (you can call it anything you want though) that `await`s the wrapped `setTimeout` function. Now that function will wait until the time has finished and then run the next piece of code.

Hope that helps!

> **a Note on browser compatibility**: Async and await is from the lastest javascript standard so it won't work on IE. [You can use babel to converter newer javascript to older javascript if you need to.](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&code_lz=GYVwdgxgLglg9mABLAtgUwBQpgGxzAZzQgQBMCBKRAbwChFEAnNKERpMNAd0QAVG42IhmYE4OAG5pEAXgB8iIlAAqMdHBBQMGKvKZoxkzBQA0ibHkLEylCgG5aAX1q1QkWAkTAYjAlEQ6NPSIAPQhiCRgfohoAB4ADgCGYKSyiKRwECDoYFAAdACOIGiMAJ4Aymg4xFBwjBgA5IkN9sFhMQnJpHkQ-BAA1joODJGGaHk4cADmjd6-_ozJLQ7ObtDwSESRpIF0DO2j_mLoUAAWMGBTaRlZOflFJRVVNXWNza374ccs55c9fYMPhEEGMJtNGlsyEwlq1VuB1p4zj4dlQ9qFwodEIlmIlrplsmhcoVimVKtVoK8Gv9EgQCMs2hiQf5InMUHjboT7iSnuTavUqSyfCh6Z9gWBWf8YAMhsFRuJxpMZg0kYxUoswPTnLQaaVIF54R4kChEhddrKmcg1AY0gBGAAMduGiGqC2SaUdLgYXHO1QC6sQAB5LehKEEGAw5n4ZeGsVwTf5UJh7Q6gQxISlo-HEnGYAmrRhk3bU8hzqrMwxs_Hg0mHUWnQx1QBqRv1sWgxUiZJA5xa42m-xAA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=true&fileSize=false&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Ces2016%2Ces2017&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0&envVersion=)

```js
function time(milliseconds) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(), milliseconds));
}

function first () {
  // const expand = document.querySelector('a');
  // expand.click();
  console.log('first ran');
}
function second() {
  // const something = document.querySelector('a');
  // something.click();
  console.log('second ran');
}
function third() {
  // const area = document.querySelector('.class');
  // const confirm = document.querySelector('.confirm');
  // confirm.click();
  console.log('third ran');
}

async function main() {
  const times = 100;
  let ran = 0;

  while (ran < times) {
    first();
    await time(1000);
    second();
    await time(1000);
    third();
    await time(1000);
    ran++;
    console.log(ran);
  }
}

main();
```

---

From your comment:

> Thanks! Also curious, the best possible solution for me would be to be able to step through these using yield so I can call main().next(). Do you know how to structure that as a generator with the same time promise? Would love the help on that

I don't think this is what you want but it sort of satisfies your requirements. Maybe I have to think about this more...

Anyway, `run` is now a function that returns a promise and in the `make` function, it `yield`s the promise `run` returns. So now in another async function you can `await` their `value`s.

Again, I don't think this is what you want but I can give you another suggestion if you clarify your intent.

```js
function time(milliseconds) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(), milliseconds));
}

function first () {
  // const expand = document.querySelector('a');
  // expand.click();
  console.log('first ran');
}
function second() {
  // const something = document.querySelector('a');
  // something.click();
  console.log('second ran');
}
function third() {
  // const area = document.querySelector('.class');
  // const confirm = document.querySelector('.confirm');
  // confirm.click();
  console.log('third ran');
}

async function run() {
  first();
  await time(1000);
  second();
  await time(1000);
  third();
  await time(1000);
}

function* make() {
  const times = 100;
  let ran = 0;

  while (ran < times) {
    yield run();
    ran++;
    console.log(ran);
  }
}

async function main() {
  const iterator = make();
  await iterator.next().value;
  await iterator.next().value;
  await iterator.next().value;
  await iterator.next().value;
}

main();
```

Comment: Awesome thanks. I had another version of the code that was almost there with async/await. The one thing I missed was wrapping the while loop inside of the async function. Thanks!

Also curious, the best possible solution for me would be to be able to step through these using yield so I can call main().next(). Do you know how to structure that as a generator with the same time promise? Would love the help on that.

Comment: I was thinking of this... but I think it just clicks the first() and toggles it again so I've done something wrong.
    
{
function* go () {
  const times = 10;
  let ran = 0;

  while (ran < times) {
    first();
    yield time(1000);
    second();
    yield time(1000);
    third();
    yield time(4000);
    fourth();
    yield time(4000);

    ran++;
  }
}

go();
}

Comment: Actually it is working now. What I'm doing is writing a script to delete all Facebook posts on a profile using Chrome DevTools console.

It's here: https://codepen.io/jamescoury/pen/ddEXqO

I am stuck at one thing now.

 It works the first time around in the loop, but then I get the error below. Any idea how to fix this? "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null
    at third (<anonymous>:25:11)
    at gogo (<anonymous>:39:5)
    at <anonymous>

Comment: I was thinking to somehow store the functions and variables to localstorage so I could keep hitting `go();` until all posts are gone.

But ideally I want it to work as a loop. I think it's a React DOM thing since the selector in `third()` is based on a class that doesn't update after the first loop iteration completes. So I'm stuck there but it feels so close.